# Program building correctly but not running

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, sdl-2

This is my code:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;

    SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    }
    else
    {
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("Title", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
        if (window == NULL)
        {
            printf("Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());

        }
        else
        {
            screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

            SDL_FillRect(screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF ));
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

            SDL_Event e; bool quit = false; while( quit == false ){ while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) ){ if( e.type == SDL_QUIT ) quit = true; } }

            SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

            SDL_Quit();

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The program builds all fine no errors no warnings no nothing. But when it comes to running it. My window pc says This app can't run on your pc. Does anyone know how to fix this?

The build system i am using is gcc mingw.

COMMAND:

```
g++ Test.cpp -I"include" -L"lib" -Wall -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2  -mwindows -o Test.exe
```

Comment: Maybe you don't have the required dlls in a folder of your `PATH` environment variable or in the same folder as your executable. Use this dependency walker replacement to help with debugging what is missing: [https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)

Comment: Looking at this program my SDL2 program is requiring 6 things. 3 of which is from my mingw folder. All 3 in the bin folder which checking my PATH enviroment variables I have in there.

Comment: SDL version?  Binary or self-built?  Are you running into a variant of [6139](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/issues/6139)?

Comment: replace all code inside `main` with `return 0;`. Does it still fail?

Comment: @Anders I have just replaced the code with just `return 0;` and it is stilling saying my PC can not run this app.

Comment: So i have manged to figure out the error is in the way i am building the program. So my orginal building solution is.
`g++ Test.cpp -I"include" -L"lib" -Wall -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2  -mwindows -o Test.exe`
but if i then change it to
`g++ Test.cpp -o Test.exe`
The programs build when it is all set to `return 0;`. So it is an error in the way i am linking my include and lib directory in the build command.